# Force create foreign key even if reference does not exist

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key

I have two tables `foo` and `bar`, `bar` has column `a` that references `foo.id` as a foreign key. When creating table `bar` before `foo`, the error `column "a" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist` is given. This is obvious and intended. However, the creation of these two tables are handled by two different entities that of which I cannot control. It's guaranteed that no data will be added to either table until both are successfully created, but the creation itself may happen out-of-order. Is there a way to force the creation of `bar` even though `foo` does not exist?

Comment: No. The integrity system doesn't care about your guarantees and assurances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick fix. you can add a semaphore that prevents the creation of bar before foo exists. Pseudocode:

```
WHILE true:
    n = (select count(1) 
         from information_schema.tables 
         where table_name = 'foo')
    if n == 1:
        break
    sleep 1

create table bar ...
```

In the long run, consider how you should handle dependencies between different parts of the system, that are created independently of each other

Comment: I guess I'll have to deal with it like this for now.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the foreign key in a separate step:

```
CREATE TABLE bar (
   id bigint PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
   a  bigint NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE foo (
   id bigint PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
);

ALTER TABLE bar ADD FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES foo (id);
```

The only condition is that the `ALTER TABLE` has to be executed *after* the other two statements, but the order in which the `CREATE TABLE` statements are issued is irrelevant.

That's the best you can do.